# How can I support multiple screen sizes in moblie game deveopment

Tags: java, android, mobile, libgdx

For this question, I am specifically referring to android.
I want to learn how to make a game and ensure that it will work on devices with different screen sizes. I test the apps on my phone, which has a huge screen. But if a user downloads it and has a smaller screen size, how will it affect the game? I'm using libGDX.

Comment: Why tag the question ios if you're referring specifically to android? And do you have an actual specific question?

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: @Andy Because I wanted an answer for how developers of all OS's do this in general. Something like the first 2 sentences in Luca's answer. I only added in that I'm developing for android, but the answer to this question doesn't have to be limited to android specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you set the dimension of a "virtual screen" that you will consider the real screen inside the game will be rendered.
This way you can easily project the dimensions of your actors ecc.

Then you use a ViewPort that scale your "virtual screen" to fill the real screen (that has its own real dimension in pixels).
Obviously there's a problem about the aspect ration.
Typically it's better to choose the dimensions of the "virtual screen" properly; for example if you choose a virtual ratio of  800x480 the game won't be look stretched on devices that has the same aspect ratio of the screen.

This in not the only solution...maybe it's better if you take a look here [https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d][1].

Luca